# What is the target of legacy directory

Tags: android, file, storage

I am confused about the locations that I can write on Android devices of all Android version
I can't understand the target of `/storage/emulated/legacy` I checked it and found that I can write on it, What the difference between it and `/storage/emulated/0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i read this has relation with the  version  JellyBeanant 4.2 the new Multi-user functionality.

storage/emulated/legacy:  this directory always pointing to the directory to the currently logged-in user.

storage/emulated/0:  is for device owners.

And probably you have the same files because just have 1 account in the device and is the same the user and the owner.

[This link hace more information about legacy and 0](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/why-did-sdcard-turn-into-sdcard-0-with-4-2)